# how to get calling method name and lineNumber in Android

Tags: android

I need to get calling method name and line number in android,I tried with

`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName())`

but this will give called method name,but I need to print calling method name,can anyone help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

For the class name

```
this.getClass().getName();
```

For line number

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber();
```

and the method would be

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
```

To access the right element from the array from the `getStackTrace()`.

Comment: Hi,instead of using getStackTrace()[2],if i use getStackTrace()[1],it is returning as getStackTrace as method name,i need to display the calling method name...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
method2(){
method1("method2");
}
method3(){
method1("method3");
}
method1(String Callingname){
Log.d("Method1", "Callingname")
}
```